# Convert html table to array (with or without rownspan/colspan) - php

Tags: php, html, dom

I've followed this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074174/Simple-Way-to-Convert-HTML-Table-Data-into-PHP-Arr

I've adapted to my code:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($table);

$header = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('th');
$content = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach ($header as $node_header) {
    $data_header[] = trim($node_header->textContent);
}
    
$i=0;
$j=0;

foreach ($content as $node_content) {
    $data_content[$j][] = trim($node_content->textContent);
    $i = $i+1;
    $j = $i % count($data_header) == 0 ? $j + 1: $j;
}
    
for ($i=0; $i < count($data_content); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < count($data_header); $j++) { 
        $temp_data[$i][$data_header[$j]] = $data_content[$i][$j];
    }
}

$data_content = $temp_data;
unset($temp_data);
return $data_content;
```

It's works, but not with rowspan or colspan attributes in td's.

The code works with this table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>head 1</th>
       <th>head 2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>body 1</td>
       <td>body 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [head 1] => body 1
            [head 2] => body 2
        )
)
```

That's perfect.
But with rowspan or colspan attributes, the result is a mess.
Any idea?

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What are you using as input? What output do you get? What output do you expect? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting errors. I want to convert any table, with or without rownspan or col span attributes. I've received a table element, and process its to array.

Comment: This code process table perfectly, without rowspan/colspan. But its not works with those attributes.

Comment: There's no magic fix here, you're going to have to implement a lot of logic in order to get everything to line up 100% of the time for all possible input. I've done something similar in Java and it still haunts my dreams.